# Overlaying text on image not working

Tags: css, overlay, mouseover

I have three images in a row. The images don't have text in them. That needs to be added with the code. I used the method described in posts here (using relative and absolute positions) and have it somewhat working. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/pcpg7zww/1/). There are two main problems.

First, the placement isn't consistent. If the window is resized, the text doesn't move with the image. On a smartphone, the text disappears completely.

Second, when the images are mousedover they expand. But if the mouse is moved over the text, the expanding stops. If I remove the z-index then the text disappears when the image is mousedover. I want to have the text always show but also to expand the image. My code is below. It is taken from the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46025747/cant-stop-animation-fro-cycling/46040548#46040548), except for the text overlay, which I added. Is it possible to add text to an image that changes and have it work as described?

```
    <style>
    .nav {margin:0; padding-top:5px;overflow:hidden}
    .nav-items {border:1px solid black}
    .nav-items {position:relative;margin-left:0px; display:inline-block; overflow: hidden;}
    .nav-items:hover img {  
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
      z-index: 2;
      -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
      -webkit-transform: scale(2.1);
      -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
      -ms-transform: scale(2.1);   
      -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
      -moz-transform: scale(2.1);
      transition: all 500ms ease-in;
      transform: scale(2.1); 
    }
    .nav-items img {
     -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
      -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      -ms-transform: scale(1); 
      -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      -moz-transform: scale(1);
      transition: all 200ms ease-in;
      transform: scale(1);   
    }
    #bannerText_0,
    #bannerText_1,
    #bannerText_2{
     position:absolute;
     font-size:20px;
     line-height: 150%;
     color:#fff;
     top:60px;
     background:transparent;
     z-index:999;
    }
    #bannerText_0{left:10%;}
    #bannerText_1{left:35%;}
    #bannerText_2{left:60%;}
    </style>

    <div class="banner_set">  
     <ul class="nav">
      <li id="0" class="nav-items"><a href="example.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/130x130"></a></li>
      <div id="bannerText_0">Img 1</div>
      <li id="1" class="nav-items"><a href="example.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/130x130"></a></li>
      <div id="bannerText_1">Img 2</div>
      <li id="2" class="nav-items"><a href="example.com"><img src="http://placehold.it/130x130"></a></li>
      <div id="bannerText_2">Img 3</div>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that the structured your HTML incorrectly - you can't put `<div>`s in between the `<li>` elements in the `<ul>`.

As well as causing the broken layout, its also the reason the mouseover on the text affects the image doesn't work - the text isn't actually inside an `nav-item` element that has the hover effect.

You can solve all your problems by putting your div's inside the `<li>` elements!

**Bonus Fix :)**, I've also fixed the space at the bottom under the image - just make the image `display:block;`.

**Your Fiddle**, updated with these changes: https://jsfiddle.net/pcpg7zww/2/

**Working snippet**:

```css
.nav {margin:0; padding-top:5px;overflow:hidden}
.nav-items {border:1px solid black}
.nav-items {position:relative;margin-left:0px; display:inline-block; overflow: hidden;}

.nav-items:hover img {  
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 150px #000000;
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(2.1);
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(2.1);   
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(2.1);
    transition: all 500ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(2.1); 
}
.nav-items img {
   -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1); 
    -ms-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -ms-transform: scale(1); 
    -moz-transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transition: all 200ms ease-in;
    transform: scale(1);   
    display:block; /* this will remove the space at the bottom */
}
#bannerText_0,
#bannerText_1,
#bannerText_2{
 position:absolute;
 font-size:20px;
 line-height: 150%;
 color:#fff;
 top:60px;
 background:transparent;
 z-index:999;
}
#bannerText_0{left:10%;}
#bannerText_1{left:35%;}
#bannerText_2{left:60%;}
```

```html
<div class="banner_set">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li id="0" class="nav-items">
      <a href="example.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
        <div id="bannerText_0">Img 1</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="1" class="nav-items">
      <a href="example.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
        <div id="bannerText_1">Img 2</div>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li id="2" class="nav-items">
      <a href="example.com">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/130x130">
        <div id="bannerText_2">Img 3</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```